# How does finding the $y$-intercept of a graph reduce error compared to finding the average of the data set?

Tags: probability, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

In my particular case I have the equation

$$
\frac{1}{d_i} = -\frac{1}{d_o}+\frac{1}{f} 
$$

and I'm plotting $\frac{1}{d_i}$ against $\frac{1}{d_o}$ to give an intercept of (in theory) -1 and a $y$-intercept of $\frac{1}{f}$. How does this reduce the error versus just taking the average of all my values for $f$? I can see how finding the slope accounts for systematic errors, as adding a constant to every $x$ or $y$ value would only increase the intercept, but I don't see how finding the intercept mitigates errors.

Comment: Aha, this must be about a lens, not a frequency. Always nice to have the context. And what are you doing with that lens?

Answer (score 0):

If you find the intercept, your result will be more heavily weighted by the points close to the Y axis (where $d_0$ is large). By contrast, if you take the average of all the $\frac{1}{f}$ values, each value will be equally weighted.

Is there a reason to believe the values of $f$ will change with $d$? Or alternatively, if there is less error in the value of $\frac{1}{d}$ for large $d$, then you will get a more accurate result.

Without knowing how the error of either quantity depends on its magnitude it's hard to make a *definitive* assertion that one method is better than the other.

Comment: The measurement uncertainty on both $d$ values are the same and constant, and there's no reason why the random error would be greater on one than the other, as they're both just distances of similar magnitude measured in the exact same way.

Comment: If the error on d is constant the relative error on 1/d decreases with d...

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed that. I'm afraid I still don't understand how this implies taking the intercept will give a more accurate value.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a difficult experiment to analyse because as the percentage error in one quantity $\frac {1}{d_\rm o}$ increases the percentage error in the other quantity $\frac {1}{d_\rm i}$ decreases and vice versa and so it is not just a case of points being more accurate at one end of the graph as compared with the other.

Think of it this way.
Assume the focal length of the lens is approximately $10\,\rm cm$ and the error in a measurement is $0.5 \, \rm cm$.
When ${d_\rm o} \approx 20 \,\rm cm$ and ${d_\rm i} \approx 20 \,\rm cm$ just adding errors gives an error in the focal length of approximately $2.5 \%$ whereas if the object is at infinity the measured focal length is in error by approximately $5 \%$.

The find the focal length as an average of many values one would have to use a weighted average with the weighting being $\dfrac{1}{\rm error^2}$ which would be quite laborious by hand or even if one set up a spread sheet to do the calculations.

Drawing a graph with appropriate error bars is not necessarily more accurate but you are in effect doing the averaging of your results with less effort.
At the same time you can use your physics knowledge to compare theory and experiment as you know that the graph should be symmetrical with the intercepts on the two axes the same $(=\frac 1f)$.

Comment: Why is the error 5% when the object is at infinity? And can you explain the weighting of the average to me?

Comment: With the object a long way away (equivalent to being at infinity) an image will be formed in the focal plane of the lens which is $10\,\rm cm$ from the lens and the error is $0.5\,\rm cm$, a percentage error of $5\%$. Weighted averages are well documented in textbooks and on Internet sites eg http://labrad.fisica.edu.uy/docs/promedios_ponderados_taylor.pdf.

Comment: Okay, I understand the weighted average and why the error is 5% when the object is at infinity (I'd calculated it wrong which is why I was confused). I still don't understand how the line of best fit is (approximately) forming a weighted average, plus I used least squares regression which isn't weighted to my understanding. However, I think this is probably beyond the scope of the task at this point and your last point about the intercepts on both axes is going to be the most valuable argument.